# The Yoneda embedding induces a monad-like structure?

Tags: category-theory

In CAT the Yoneda embedding $C^{\text{op}} \stackrel{y_C}{\to} \text{hom}(C, \text{Set})$, induces a map $$\text{hom}(\text{hom}(C, \text{Set}), \text{Set}) \stackrel{y^*_C}{\to} \text{hom}(C^{\text{op}}, \text{Set})$$

Thus, if we call $T = \text{hom}(\_, \text{Set})$.
We have a map (which is not even dinatural): $$\_^{\text{op}} \stackrel{\iota}{\to} T$$ and a kind of multiplication,

$$T^2 \stackrel{\mu}{\to} T \circ \_^{\text{op}}. $$

Is there a way to say that this is *contravariant monad* on CAT?! I looked online for such a notion and I did not find anything.

---

Note, even if $\iota$ is not dinatural, i.e. $f^*y_Hf \neq y_G, $ for a functor $G \stackrel{f}{\to} H$, looking at CAT as a 2-category, there is a $2$-cell $$y_G \Rightarrow f^*y_Hf.$$

---

I am receiving some interesting comments on [Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301625/the-yoneda-embedding-induces-a-monad-like-structure).